# Let $A$ be an integral domain and $I$ be an fractional ideal of $A$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, abelian-groups

Let $A$ be an integral domain and $I$ be an fractional ideal of $A$.
Why any two elements of $I$ are $A$-linearly dependent ?
I guess this is true, but I couldn't find any reffenrece for this.

If this is a famous fact, reference is also appreciated.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $I$ is a fractional ideal of $A$, then $I$ is an $A$-submodule of $Frac(A)$ and there exists an $a \in A$, $a \neq 0$ such that $aI \subseteq A$. Suppose $x, y \in I$. Then $ax \in A$ and $ay \in A$. Note that we have that $(-ay)x+(ax)y = 0$ in $A$ because we have $(-ay)x = -a(yx) = -a(xy) = -(ax)y$ in $Frac(A)$.

Comment: Hello, I'm nekojiru, one of japanese cat. The last equalities holds because $Frac(A)$ is a field ?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. All those elements are in $Frac(A)$, a field.

Comment: Thank you, cat is very pretty. I want to reborn as a cat, because my life as pencil was very unhappy.